# Interface for custom cast-function

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a custom cast function template (that looks and works similar to `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, you name it). For the sake of an example I have a function template called `checked_cast` that casts downwards in a polymorphic class hierarchy, performing a check in debug builds wether the cast is valid and omitting the check in release builds. A simple implementation could look like this:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To checked_cast(From* p) {
    assert(dynamic_cast<To>(p) != nullptr && "Invalid cast");
    return static_cast<To>(p); // We just hope that there is no virtual inheritance involved... 
}
```

Now at call sites this cast is invoked like this:

```
Base* b = /* ... */;
auto* d = checked_cast<Derived*>(b);
Base const* bc = b;
auto* dc = checked_cast<Derived const*>(bc);
// ...
```

However, the cast could also be implemented such that at the call sites only the target type would be specified, without cv-pointer/ref qualifications:

```
Base* b = /* ... */;
auto* d = checked_cast<Derived>(b); // Result type Derived* is deduced from argument type.
Base const* bc = b;
auto* dc = checked_cast<Derived>(bc); // Result type Derived const* is also deduced.
// ...
```

Now I wonder if there are arguments that either way to write this is better or worse than the other or if one of them is more 'idiomatic' than the other.

Some arguments I can come up with:

- The first version is more in line with the built in `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` etc.
- The second version is used by [`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)/`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`.
- The second version may be easier to use in generic code where you don't have direct access to the cv-ref/pointer qualifiers of the origin type.
- It may be more cumbersome to always type the cv-ref/pointer qualifiers.
- The code may be easier to read with explicit qualifiers.

I plan to use a cast interface like this in my project and want to make an informed decision before I commit to one of the two versions and use them all over the place.

Comment: IMHO I would not do this.  You violate the principle of least surprise.  The `name_cast<destination_type>(source)` expression all cast `source` to the type of `destination_type`.  Having your custom cast operator not follow that can/will lead to bugs/issues, especially with people new to the code base.

Comment: The simple implementation has a fundamental flaw: being able to `dynamic_cast` doesn't mean you can `static_cast`. Virtual bases break this. I'd go with `To res = dynamic_cast<To>(p): assert(res != nullptr); return res;`

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you, I did not know this. However the question is about the interface, the `checked_cast` function is just an example.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` already throws an exception if you cast to a reference so I'm not sure your custom cast is necessary?

Comment: `std::(static|dynamic)_pointer_cast` don't take a pointer type because they operate on `std::shared_ptr`, which doesn't take a pointer type. But if you are going to be operating on a raw pointer, don't model your cast on `std::(static|dynamic)_pointer_cast`.

Comment: On the principle of least surprise, Unreal Engine's `Cast<>()` functions work this way for its UObjects.  There's a hook into `dynamic_cast` (via a `#define`) to allow natural C++ casting but it hasn't seen widespread adoption amongst UE devs, likely because `dynamic_cast` is the surprising behaviour.  So, I'd suggest going with the expectations of your intended audience.

Comment: Thank you all, your comments helped me, I will go with the first approach.